# Apache Shiro per object permission?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, permissions, acl, shiro

Is it possible to implement a per database row permission system with Shiro? Suppose I have 10000 records in a table and some user can only see 1000 records... what is the best way to only return those records to the user? Is this a Shiro "use case" or I'm totally in the wrong path here? Thanks

Comment: +1 I'm intending to do the same thing, if I get there first will let you know.

Comment: What determines if they can see it or not?

Comment: @SoltiriosDelimanolis a user manages various client accounts so the user should only be able to see the accounts they have permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a case for a join table.

USER_RECORD Table: USER_ID | RECORD_ID

```
select record_id, record_field_1, record_field_2, ... 
from record r, user u, user_record ur
where ur.user_id = u.user_id
and ur.record_id = r.record_id
and u.user_id = :userId
```